# How to count values matches in another column

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a query system where a person post a query, db allocated an id (query_id) to that query. I am using that query_id in another column query_reply_id in same table to store the data of send emails. Now I am trying to count the number of emails sent on that id, following code giving me the number of emails sent per id in MySQL but when I call it, the preview shows it combine.

```
$new_sql = "SELECT t.query_id, count(o.query_reply_id) mycount 
            from query t 
               left join query o on t.query_id = o.query_reply_id 
            Where t.query_form = 'contactus' 
              AND t.query_status= 'replied' 
            group by o.query_reply_id 
            order by t.query_reply_date DESC";

$new_run = mysqli_query($conn, $new_sql);
while($new_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($new_run)){

echo $new_rows['mycount'];}

query_id  mycount
70          1
23          8
43          11
49          1
```

In preview, its showing 18111 against each of the query.

Comment: add a line break after echoing each row

Comment: Thanks for the reply but query Id 70 should have 1 against it, on <br> its giving all my count values against 70.. and so on

Comment: Thanks, its solved.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a long line with just the mycount values is that all you are echoing out are mycount values.

You need to add a line break at the end *and* output the query_id values too. Perhaps something a bit like this:

```
while($new_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($new_run)){
    echo $new_rows['query_id'], ':', $new_rows['mycount'],"<br />";
}
```

Personally, as this is tabular data I'd be tempted to use a table.

This sort of thing:

```
echo "<table><tr><td>query_id</td><td>mycount</td></tr>";
while($new_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($new_run)){
    echo '<tr><td>' ,$new_rows['query_id'], '</td><td>', $new_rows['mycount'],"</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table";
```